# Error while including glad with glfw in c++

Tags: c++, glfw, glad

Can anyone please tell me what wrong in this picture because for some reasons it did not work at all
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FglTc.png)

I tried GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE already and yes, I tried everything I found in the internet already but the error still there

Comment: The first thing that is wrong with the picture is that it is a picture. Please [do not upload pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Why are you (apparently) trying to use both `glew` *and* `glad`?  Just remove the `#include <glew.h>` to see if that helps.